# Find the relative path from two absolute paths

Tags: rust, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'd like to return the relative path from an absolute path.

E.g.:

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let any_path = PathBuf::from("/abc/def/foo/bar".to_string());
    let current = PathBuf::from("/abc/def/here".to_string());
    
    println!("The relative path is: {:?}", make_relative(&any_path, &current));
}
```

The function `make_relative` should do that work in order to have this output:

```
The relative path is: "../foo/bar"
```

Comment: @vallentin `pathdiff::diff_paths(&any_path, &current)` => `Some("../foo/bar")` ? Do you mean the `Some`? I'm sure the OP can find their way to `Option::unwrap`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I already removed the comment, I skimmed too quickly and only interpreted `Path::strip_prefix` :)